# Matching previous and current records WITH and WITHOUT LAG and LEAD

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like below. Records do not have any primary key and I want to achieve it both WITH and WITHOUT LAG and LEAD function.

```
ID      ENTID     INOUTDATE             YEAR    MONTH   STATUS
1923    1923    [NULL]                  2099     12      Out
1923    10690   [NULL]                  2099     12      Out
1923    9670    2012-08-24 00:00:00     2012     8       In
1923    1923    2013-06-01 00:00:00     2013     6       In
1923    9670    2018-04-19 00:00:00     2018     4       Out
1923    10690   2019-02-01 00:00:00     2019     2       In
```

And I want to get the records as per below.

```
ID      ENTID     INOUTDATE             YEAR    MONTH   STATUS
1923    10690   [NULL]                  2099    12      Out
1923    9670    2012-08-24 00:00:00     2012    8       In
1923    9670    2018-04-19 00:00:00     2018    4       Out
1923    10690   2019-02-01 00:00:00     2019    2       In
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `lad()`/`lead()`?  What is the logic for the filtering you want to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have edited my question. If possible can you show the both way. Thanks.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Probably so they can support versions older than when `LAG()`/`LEAD()` were introduced.

Answer (score 1):

`lag()` is the simplest method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(status) over (partition by id, (case when inoutdate is null then 1 else 2 end)
                               order by inoutdate
                              ) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status;
```

You can treat this as a group-and-islands problem, identifying the islands using  `row_number()`.  The logic is more complicated:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id, (case when inoutdate is null then 1 else 2 end), status, (seqnum - seqnum_s)
                                order by inoutdate
                               ) as seqnum_g
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by id, (case when inoutdate is null then 1 else 2 end) order by inoutdate) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by id, (case when inoutdate is null then 1 else 2 end), status order by inoutdate) as seqnum_s
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum_g = 1;
```